# Pass varchar param to sql file via Batch file

Tags: sql, batch-file

I have a batch file which runs multiple sql files and passes parameters to them.
The input parameters are stored in a txt file which is read by batch file.

I am trying to pass varchar values to `IN` clause of SQL.

For e.g.

In my **input file** i this entry

```
var1="'tommy','jim'"
```

**In Batch file**

```
<code to read file , assuming %1 has the var1 value>
set param=%~1

sqlplus %DBCONN% @%programFolder%\test.sql %param%
```

**test.sql**  (name is varchar2)

```
select * from table where name in (&1);
```

---

This gives error, saying invalid number 
as it tries to run

`select * from table where name in (tommy);`

---

If i echo right before the sql stmt, its displays 'tommy','jim'
but in sql its removing jim and the single quotes ...

Please help!

---

Now i  edited entry in Input file as
`var1="'''tommy''','''jim'''"`

it goes as `select * from table where name in ('tommy');`

But it truncates the second value

Any clue how to include comma ??

Comment: Can you share more details on how you fixed this? I have following code in place
//read input file- ('pdf','csv','jpeg','png')
set /P ALLOWED_TYPES=<Allowed_TYPEs.txt

sqlplus %connection_DB% @SQL_CMD.txt %ALLOWED_TYPES%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Finally found a way**

input file - 
`var1=('tommy','jim')`

Remove the braces from the sql file 
`select * from table where name in &1;`

This works , i have no idea why was taking a comma was such an issue, there should have been some way to pass the comma ! 
If anyone finds out please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The tilde (`~`) strips quotes from the variable.

Try using `var1='tommy','jim'` in your input file and `set param=%1` in your batch script.

Comment: If i remove tilde, the param is separated in batch itself. `echo %var1%` before the sql displays only 'tommy'